# Googlesheets - Merge sheets from the same document

Tags: google-sheets

I wish to merge subsheets: Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 into one sheet: Merged.
And Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Merged all in the same spreadsheet document.

Now I can do it with below formula:

```
=query({importrange("sheetKey","Q4!A1:L900");importrange("sheetKey","Q3!A1:L900"); importrange("sheetKey","Q2!A1:L900"); importrange("sheetKey","Q1!A1:L900")}, "Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col11 where Col11 is not null")
```

My question is:

1. Since all are subsheets in the same document,can we ignore the "sheetKey" field?
2. If not, can we define a varialbe for "sheetKey" then use it for short? The sheetKey usually 44 characters,it's so long and make my formula hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need importrange to import data from sheets/tabs within the same spreadsheet.

```
=query({Q4!A1:L900; Q3!A1:L900; Q2!A1:L900; Q1!A1:L900"}, "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col11 where Col11 is not null", 0)
```

Comment: Awesome,that what I expected!